# How to assign probabilities to individual sample points in a tree diagram

Tags: conditional-probability

[image]

Referring to the image , i have understood how probabilities are assigned to elements of sample space , S . Now , when we aim to calculate P(E|F) we consider F to be our new sample space for event E . So how do we assign the probabilities now to the elements of set F (like it was done for elements of S) ? Because i want to simply add P((T,5)) and P((T,6)) ,that is using the axiomatic theory of probability to get P(E|F) without using P(E and F )/P(F) which is the conventional formula to calculate conditional probability . I tried it a lot but wasn't able to do it .I just tried to back calculate it from   the given  answer  for P(E|F) 
Which is 2/9 ( they used the formula ) ,  which implies that P((T,5)) and P((T,6)) are 2/9*1/2 which is 1/9 . So all of the P((T,i)) are 1/9 which makes it 2/3 and the one remaining P((H,T)) is 1/3 considering F as the sample space . But how do we determine directly these probabilities which i back calculated . Someone please help .

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: To format what , what is not clear ?